# Firebase Cloud Shell security rules emulator gives error 400

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I'm exploring Cloud Shell emulator for firebase security rules and in the tutorial I'm getting the below error on `npm --prefix=functions test` (step 4.5 of the tutorial, [here is the link](https://ssh.cloud.google.com/cloudshell/editor?environment_deployment=firebase&walkthrough_tutorial_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwalkthroughs.googleusercontent.com%2Fcontent%2Ffirebase_emulator_rules_quickstart%2Ffirebase_emulator_rules_quickstart.md) to the tutorial in case it's publicly accessible):

> functions@ test
> /home/user/rules-tutorial/quickstart-testing/cs-walkthrough/functions
>
> mocha --timeout 5000
>
> body {"error":{"code":400,"message":"Payload
> isn't valid for request.","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT"}}
>
> 0 passing (40ms)
>
> 1 failing
>
> 1. "before all" hook in "{root}":
>
>    Payload isn't valid for request.

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same error.

Go to: `rules-tutorial/quickstart-testing/cs-walkthrough/functions/test.js`

Find this line and explicitly specify the encoding type:

```
  const rulesContent = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "../firestore.rules"));
```

like this:

```
  const rulesContent = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "../firestore.rules"), 'utf-8');
```

I hope the GCloud team will fix it in a future release.

[image]